# JavaScript onClick on embedded elements

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript:

```
<div>
    <tr onClick="click1()">
        <td>
            click 1
        </td>
        <td onClick="click2()">
            click 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

```js
function click1() {
  alert(1);
}

function click2() {
  alert(2);
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr onClick="click1()">
    <td>
      click 1
    </td>
    <td onClick="click2()">
      click 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If I click 'click 1', the `click1()` function is called as expected. If I click 'click 2', the `click1()` & `click2()` functions are both called.

**Question**

How do I make the click on 'click 2' only call the `click2()` function, and not call the `click1()` function?

Comment: put the `onClick` attribute into the `td` tag of click 1

Comment: Add `event.stopPropagation();` in your click2 function.

Comment: The fact that there are two different "answers" to this question hints at the fact it should be closed as it does not show any research effort.

Comment: @noah1400, thanks for your reply.  I cannot, because what I am trying to  achieve is if the user click on the row, it calls function `click1()`. However, if they click on a specific item in the row it calls function `click2()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the easiest way is just to move your 'click 1' trigger to the button itself:

```html
<div>
    <tr>
        <td onClick="click1()">
            click 1
        </td>
        <td onClick="click2();">
            click 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

However, I'm assuming you want to keep the `click 1` trigger where it is, in which case you can add `event.stopPropagation()` to the event:

```html
<div>
   <tr onClick="click1();">
       <td>
           click 1
       </td>
       <td onClick="click2(); event.stopPropagation();">
           click 2
       </td>
   </tr>
</div>
```